# AJAX Control Tookit Sep Release Anti XSS

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx

As per the above link, there's supposedly 3 DLLs that come with the download that need to be referenced.

> The AntiXSS Sanitizer Provider is included in the SanitizerProviders folder with the CodePlex release of the Ajax Control Toolkit. You need to add a reference to all three assemblies contained in the folder: SanitizerProviders.dll, AntiXSSLibrary.dll, and HtmlSanitizationLibrary.dll.

However, after downloading the library from http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/, I only see 2 DLLs in the SanitizerProviders folder:

- HtmlAgilityPack.dll
- SanitizerProviders.dll

Where is that AntiXSS DLL located?

Comment: This answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022493/could-not-load-type-ajaxcontroltoolkit-sanitizer-antixsssanitizerprovider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AntiXSS is a stand alone library that you can download from MS Site

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589

Relative: [How to Include Anti-XSS in ASP.Net 2.0 Without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182253/how-to-include-anti-xss-in-asp-net-2-0-without-visual-studio)

Comment: OK, got that - thanks - but now the web.config is giving a run-time error of "Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider'.". And what's with the AJAX docs, should be updated...

Comment: @Rivka If you did not have any error previously then remove it. If you still have the same error, then read the other link that I have, to copy that library to your bin directory.

Comment: I had that error before too but attributed it to the fact that the AntiXSS lib wasn't included in the AJAX toolkit, so the namespace doesn't exist. What's the correct namespace I should be using now?